# How to optimize memory without calling System.gc();

Tags: java, memory, optimization, garbage-collection

I am currently making an application that scan a folder and create Song for each file.

```
[loop]
         if(!alreadyInLibrary(folder.getAbsolutePath())){
            Song s = new Song(folder.getAbsolutePath());
            this.addSong(s); // Add the song

            // Clear
            s = null;
            System.gc();
          }
[end loop]
```

If I call the GC my app consumme 150Mb of memory and 400Mb without. But calling GC each time is really slow. So, I wonder if there is another way to optimize memory.

Thanks

Comment: The best way is to simply write your code and forget about "optimizing memory".

Comment: (And if you must do something, try to reduce the number of objects you create.  I don't know it to be the case for sure, but there's a fair chance that `getAbsolutePath` returns a newly constructed String every time it's called, so assigning that to a temp rather than executing it twice might help and can't possibly hurt.)

Comment: You could ask on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) how to make your code more memory efficient. Showing the code in `alreadyInLibrary` would help too.

Comment: There's almost no reason to ever write `s = null;`  When the loop ends, the variable goes out of scope and then the object will no longer be referenced.

Comment: You'll need to say more about what you're trying to do. Is a `Song` a whole Song file? In that case, it might be better to stream the contents of the file when needed, and only store a pointer to it (like it's file path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should *never* call `System.gc()`. GC is a sophisticated software component and it knows itself when to work and how much memory to free on each cycle.

Moreover explicit invocation of `System.gc()` does not really call GC. It just politely asks GC to work. It can start, but can postpone the request.

This means that if you do not call GC the program runs until GC determines that it should work and then frees it. So, the answer to your question is "just do not worry about the memory. Let GC to do its work when it thinks it is the time to work."

But. All this is relevant only if you do not have memory leaks that can happen for example if you store some not needed information in long-live collections. Such entries should be cleaned programmatically.

The "right" way to work with GC in java is via various `-X` command line switches. The first step is just try to reduce the max heap limit, e.g. `-Xmx180m`. Why 180? Just because you said that when you invoke GC it occupies 150M. Now try again. If program runs well and performance is better now, try to reduce memory even more. Take a look on other GC configuration parameters if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Song s = new Song(folder.getAbsolutePath());
this.addSong(new Song(folder.getAbsolutePath())); // Add the song

// Clear
s = null;
System.gc();
```

This is asinine. The most memory efficient way to do this is simply:

```
this.addSong(new Song(folder.getAbsolutePath())); // Add the song
```

You never used s. You just created it, then set it to null, then GC'd it. Instead just add it directly. No need to do any premature optimization of this.

There's no need to call the GC. It will run when it needs to. You generally never really need to call GC.

Comment: Actually, it would be significantly more "optimal" to assign `folder.getAbsolutePath()` to a temp prior to the `if`, and use that temp in both the `if` and the `new Song` call.

Comment: @HotLicks Sure. I was mainly referring to the creation and storing of Songs.

Comment: Thank. But that always consume 400Mb.

Comment: @cyprieng Can you explain a little bit about why you need the memory to be available IMMEDIATELY? If anything needs the memory, the JVM will garbage collect for you.

Comment: @HotLicks Really? I've taken a block of code, and reduced it to a significantly smaller block of code, cutting out unnecessary object creation and GC call. How does that not make sense? I apologize that you're unable to understand it.

Comment: You removed the `alreadyInLibrary` call without knowing it's needed or not.

Comment: @HotLicks No. I didn't. I said this block of code, can be replaced with this block of code. If you were to do a find/replace of both of those blocks then you have a working example. Yes, as a whole it can be optimized slightly, but that's peanuts compared to the rest of the question. Which is the part I'm specifically focusing on. I don't really care about the if statement.

Comment: @Cruncher you are right. Sorry for my lack of knowledge about memory management.

Comment: I think the problem here is the Song class. It may be eagerly loading the song. If you just store the path in the Song it should not be an issue no matter how many times you create a Song instance.

Comment: Is evident in the 400MB consumption. If the purpose is just to get the MetaData of the MP3, and just get that. But do not load the entire MP3 in the Song. And if playing it, one must stream the song and not store it in Memory.